# Solution Explorer window is misplaced Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am facing an issue my solution explorer window goes up and I don't know how to bring it back to the same place. I restart my visual studio several times. I have also tried to **restore down** and maximize the window but have not fixed it. Here is the image

[image: Full Screen Image]

Answer (score 0):

Try restore down the VS window and then dock the toolbox

Comment: I have tried minimize and maximize screen already but it stays at the top